# How do you add text from CSV to group of tif images?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that contains 100 rows with two columns: ImageFileName and TextToWrite.

I would like to add the text from the CVS's TextToWrite column to the tif in the same row with Python. I have seen some solutions to write text to single files (like below), but I am not sure how to have the code work through the CSV file and print the text to the individual tif images.

````
my_image = Image.open("image.jpg")

title_font = ImageFont.truetype('font.ttf', 200)

image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
image_editable.text((15,15), "Text goes here", (237, 230, 211), font=title_font)

my_image.save("image-text.jpg")```
````

Comment: "but I am not sure how to have the code work through the CSV file and print the text to the individual tif images." Well, do you know how to work with a CSV file *at all*? If you don't, then [please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) do your own [research](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+csv) first, at least until you have a *specific* question about where you are getting stuck. If you are familiar with "working through the CSV file" to do anything, then start with the code to do that, and then try making the "do anything" part be the image creation.

Comment: As it stands, the *problem*, and therefore the *question*, is **not about OpenCV or images at all**; those things are only part of *why you are asking*. The goal is to understand how to get text out of the CSV file. To do this, you first need a *specification* of *how* the text is organized in the CSV file - a *rule that tells you*, for a given CSV input, how many images should be created and what text should be on each.

Comment: Hi Karl, Karl and Karl. I honestly have no idea if you are joking with me or just trying to make me feel dumb. I said the CSV has two columns. One contains the image filename and the other contains the text to write to it. Each row is another image and text to write.

Comment: I misread the question, but the response stands: do you know how to process a csv file at all? For example, did you try the web search linked above, and look at the `csv` standard library module? Is the question about that, or is it about how to link the two things together, or just what?

Comment: I ended up just reiterating the code I pasted on the question with one instance for each filename and text I want printed. If you misread what I wrote maybe you weren't interested in the question and just wanted to talk down to someone asking for help. Thanks.